# Split string in two strings by possition

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to split a string to in two different strings

I want to make a function that will take first letter from the string and push it to another string, then take second letter and push it to another string, then restart the loop and start from the place it stopped

Example:

imagine i have this string `let string = ['SOMEMESSAGE'];`

and i want it to be like this:

```
let firtsLetters = ['SMMSAE'];
let secondLetters= ['OEESG'];
```

Comment: I have a feeling this may be some homework assignment.

Comment: Where is your actual attempt here? This is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show what you actually tried first of all.

Comment: Rather trivial using a loop, index-based character access and string concatenation … https://jsfiddle.net/sg6to0j7/

Comment: And btw., a string, and an array _containing_ one string, are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example split the string into an array, then`Array#filter` over it, according to the index of currently looped element. Then - join the array to get the string.

```js
const string = 'SOMEMESSAGE';

const firstLetters = [...string].filter((_, i) => !(i % 2)).join('');
const secondLetters = [...string].filter((_, i) => i % 2).join('');

console.log(firstLetters);
console.log(secondLetters);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your string is an array of strings. Like this

```
let text = ['SOMEMESSAGE', 'MYNAME'];
```

If you want to loop through an arrays of strings you can use following.

```
let text = ['SOMEMESSAGE', 'MYNAME'];

            let arrya1 = [];
            let array2 = [];

            text.forEach((ch,i)=>
            {
                x = 0;
                for(var n of ch) {
                     (x % 2 == 0) ? arrya1.push(ch.charAt(x)) : array2.push(ch.charAt(x))
                     x++;
                }
            });

             const firstLetters = arrya1.join('');
             const secondLetters = array2.join('');

    console.log(text);
    console.log(firstLetters);
    console.log(secondLetters);
```